# where is memory missing in top?

Tags: linux, operating-system

Here is an output from top (sorted by **%Mem**):

```
Mem:   5796624k total,  4679932k used,  1116692k free,   317652k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,  1734160k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                          
13169 storm     20   0 3279m 344m  16m S  0.7  6.1 201:38.40 java                                                                                                                              
 5463 storm     20   0 2694m 172m  14m S  0.0  3.0  72:38.49 java                                                                                                                              
 5353 storm     20   0 2561m 155m  14m S  0.0  2.7  30:20.43 java                                                                                                                              
13102 app       20   0 3813m  80m  17m S  0.3  1.4 132:37.16 java                                                                                                                              
13147 storm     20   0 3876m  65m  16m S  0.0  1.2  23:21.73 java                                                                                                                              
 3081 named     20   0  230m  16m 2652 S  0.0  0.3   1:22.81 named                                                                                                                             
29773 root      20   0  318m  10m 3576 S  0.0  0.2   5:59.41 logstash-forwar                                                                                                                   
 5345 root      20   0  193m  10m 1552 S  0.0  0.2  12:24.21 supervisord                                                                                                                       
 1048 root      20   0  249m 5200 1068 S  0.0  0.1   0:22.55 rsyslogd                                                                                                                          
21774 root      20   0 99968 3980 3032 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 sshd                                                                                                                              
 3456 postfix   20   0 81108 3432 2556 S  0.0  0.1   0:02.83 qmgr                                                                                                                              
 3453 root      20   0 80860 3416 2520 S  0.0  0.1   0:19.40 master
```

In GBs:

```
Mem:   5.8g total,  4.7g used,  1.1g free,   0.3g buffers
```

So free mem is 1.1 / 5.8 ~ 19%

Where as if we add the top %Mem, we see the used is about: 6.1+3.0+2.7+1.4+1.2+0.3+... ~ 16% and that means the free should be about 84%

Why dont the numbers match (19% vs 84%)?

Comment: You need to add the memory used by  buffers + cached too. See e.g. http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the memory usage related lines in top:

```
Mem:   5796624k total,  4679932k used,  1116692k free,   317652k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,  1734160k cached
```

Total memory equals the sum of used and free memory. Used, on the other hand, is the sum of "really used by applications" and cached and buffers. So, in your case goes like this:

```
Mem = 5796624k = 4679932k + 1116692k;
"Really used by applications" = Used - (cached + buffers) 
                              = 4679932k - (1734160k + 317652k ) 
                              = 2628120k.
```

So total memory is 5.8g and 2.6g is really used by applications. Since, 1.1g is free which means `5.8g - (1.1g + 2.6g) = 2.1g` memory is cached which improves performance. In the very moment an application requires part of the cached memory it is immediately given to it. That's why your computation of free memory in percentage of total memory is not matching as you were expecting!